# why does speedtest display other country

Tags: server, squid

I live in Southeast Asia, but when I use speedtest.net to check my internet connection, that's displaying as Mercer (US).

FYI:
I use linux mint and ubuntu server as proxy (squid)
Thank

Comment: As far as I know Speedtest picks the fastest connection to any server no matter where you are.

Comment: Is it fault of my ISP so pick that connections that very far ?

Answer (score 0):

This probably means that your IP address seems to be in America, or that there are no Speedtest servers in your area.

Comment: if I use other _ISP_, it will displays my country

Comment: @sahmada the other ISP has probably registered their IP adresses in your country

Comment: If I directly connect to modem and open _speedtest.net_ its results displaying my country, but if I connect behind the squid **proxy** displays Mercer (US)

Comment: @sahmada that's because your proxy is based in Mercer

Comment: , where I have to change it ?

Comment: @sahmada what is the proxy setup like?

Comment: what do you mean about my squid.conf ?

Comment: @sahmada is your server also connected to the same modem?

Comment: yes, I use the same modem when I test connection directly to modem and behind proxy

Comment: Any other proxies or tunnels on the server?

Comment: no other proxies or tunnels on the server

Comment: you are right, my laptop ip is 168.168.X.XXX/21 and when I do 'whois 168.168.X.XXX' yeild  MERCERNET (US)

Comment: is _speedtest.net_ use my laptop ip address to test connection ? doesnt modem ip ?

Comment: @sahmada it depends on your setup. If you have not enabled on your modem, your modem ip will be used. If you are using a router instead, the ip might differ